# How to add product image url value to mysql query

Tags: magento-1.7, database

**Brief**

Add the product image URL to an existing query. Unless there is a better solution, I would like to:

1. Grab the 'value' from *catalog_product_entity_media_gallery*
2. Prefix 'www.domain.co.uk/media/catalog' to the 'value'
3. Add that to the below query

**Current Query**

```
SELECT
    increment_id AS 'Order Number',
    items.created_at AS 'Order Date',
    items.sku AS 'SKU',
    customer_email AS 'Email',
    items.name AS 'Product'
FROM sales_flat_order AS orders 
    JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS items 
    ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id 
WHERE
    orders.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-1 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 00:00:00'
```

**Current Output**

```
Order Number   Order Date           Email    SKU     Product
00001          2016-01-01 00:00:00  a@b.com  123456  Thing
00002          2016-02-01 00:00:00  b@b.com  789456  Thing 2
```

**Required Output**

```
Order Number   Order Date           Email    SKU     Product   Image URL
00001          2016-01-01 00:00:00  a@b.com  123456  Thing     www.domain.co.uk/media/catalog/image0001.jpg
00002          2016-02-01 00:00:00  b@b.com  789456  Thing 2   www.domain.co.uk/media/catalog/image0002.jpg
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: are you needed product image in order?

Comment: The product image for each SKU within an order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    increment_id AS 'Order Number',
    items.created_at AS 'Order Date',
    items.sku AS 'SKU',
    customer_email AS 'Email',
    items.name AS 'Product',
    concat('www.domain.co.uk/media/catalog/product', cpev.value) AS 'Image URL'
FROM sales_flat_order AS orders 
    JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS items 
    ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id 
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev ON cpev.entity_id = items.product_id AND attribute_id = 85
WHERE
    orders.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 00:00:00'
```

Is the SQL answer to your question. It's not a very good answer though, have you checked the results your existing query is giving you? It will, for instance, return multiple rows when you've sold a configurable product, because the configurable and it's simple are both in sales_flat_order_item with their respective `product_id`s. Still, maybe this will work for you, it'll probably run quicker than loading all the sales orders into a collection and iterating them.

--

- cpev is a table alias, it's not necessary to use AS for a table alias with mysql, or did you mean what's the table for? It's one of magento's EAV tables. This [inchoo article](http://inchoo.net/magento/magentos-database-layout-and-its-eav-structure/) explains what EAV is (a headache).
- 85 is the `id` for `image` `attribute_code` in the `eav_attribute` table. Your `id` for that code could be different, but I think that's unlikely. (There are two attributes `image`, `entity_type_id` 3 is for categories, 4 is for products)

Comment: Richard, your answer is spot on to what I was hoping the output would look like. Thank you so much. Just so that I can learn from your answer (rather than just copy&paste it), can you explain your use of "cpev" and "85" for me, please?

Comment: answered in edit

Answer (score 0):

First You Need to store `image` in tabel than you can fetch

```
    SELECT
        increment_id AS 'Order Number',
        items.created_at AS 'Order Date',
        items.sku AS 'SKU',
        customer_email AS 'Email',
        items.name AS 'Product'
        Image As 'image' 
    FROM sales_flat_order AS orders 
        JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS items 
        ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id 

WHERE
    orders.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-1 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 00:00:00'
```